# Read an excel file with Python and modify it without changing the formating and the style of the file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openxlsx

I have an excel file which has some cells with comments and colors.
I'm using python and the pandas and openpyxl libraries to read the file and adding a new row with details to it.
After the code finished to run I saw the file changed completely, like it deleted all the formating and the style of the file.
I want it to add the row but without making any change to the file formating and style.
What i need to do to prevent it to do so?
Do I need to use other library? and if that is the case which library should i use?

I tried the xlsxWriter library but it didnt work for me.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). OpenPyXL should preserve formatting so it would be good to have an example to start from

Answer (score 1):

You could try the pandas.ExcelWriter. Example:

existing_file.xlsx file:
[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
# Read the existing Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('existing_file.xlsx')

# Create a new dataframe with the new row
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['black'], 'value': ['2']})
df = pd.concat([df, new_row], ignore_index=True)

# Write the dataframe to the existing Excel file using ExcelWriter
with pd.ExcelWriter('existing_file.xlsx', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
```

existing_file.xlsx file:
[image]

pandas version: *pandas==2.0.3*

**EDIT: Removing the row (requested in comments)**

```
# Read the existing Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('existing_file.xlsx')

# Remove the row with the value 'black'
df = df.drop(df[df['key'] == 'green'].index)

# Write the updated DataFrame to the Excel file using ExcelWriter
with pd.ExcelWriter('existing_file.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
```

Result: [image]

**EDIT2: Another way of removing the row**

Before: [image]

```
import openpyxl 

path = 'existing_file.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.active
sheet.delete_rows(idx=3)
path1 = 'final.xlsx'
wb.save(path1)
```

After:

[image]

Comment: Welcome :) acccept the answer please then ;)

Comment: I tried but it gave this comment "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: And I have another question if i want to remove a row from the same file with the style and formating without changing it how to do it?

Comment: I tried to use the same code but it didnt work. For example I wanted it to remove the code with the colors but it moved the table up and kept the colurs at the same place.

Comment: To drop the certain row you can just use something like that:

# Remove the row with the value 'green'
df = df.drop(df[df['key'] == 'green'].index)

# Write the updated DataFrame to the Excel file using ExcelWriter
with pd.ExcelWriter('existing_file.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

Comment: I edited the answer to include that

Comment: lets just say I have column A all in color red. when I remove the 1 row like you did after the code saves the excel it turns all other rows in the table to a white color again (it changes the style of the table). It something in my code? It works for you?

Comment: Please check the 2nd edit. You are right that using pandas it overwrites the formatting, but it works fine with openpyxl.

Comment: Yes it worked with openpyxl. Thanks :)